# PyInstaller .exe file not working

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

**EDIT:** I found out that the error is that the resources couldn't be opened. Copying the directory into the folder where the .exe is didn't fix it. I tried removing the resources from the .spec file and the size of the .exe file is now 9 MB as opposed to 52 MB so I'm pretty sure the resources are included, but somehow they can't seem to be opened by the .exe. In case anything is wrong with it, [This](http://pastebin.com/mP7K3G8w) is my .spec file - I only modified the Tree thing to include the resources, the .exe filename and icon.

In other words, the question now is: **Why can't the exe find my game resources, and what do I have to do to fix that? Also, I realised my resources folder has two subfolders - does that mean I have to go about writing the Tree differently?**

I've made a game in Python (using Pygame, too) and want to make a single executable file so I can distribute it. PyInstaller seemed perfect for that, and eventually, after a while of searching, I found out how to get it working in [this guide](http://irwinkwan.com/tag/pyinstaller/). After I tweaked my code to get step 2 working I created the .spec file, added the directory with the resources to it (as in step 5, and including the font file), copied it to the same folder the .spec file was in and finally I ran

```
build.py game.spec
```

and I found the .exe file exactly where it was supposed to be. However, when I open it, it just closes again after a few seconds, and I think it's just before the main menu shows up. I'm not really sure it's a font screw-up again though because I made sure to include it in the resources as well...

Unfortunately, searching for a solution on the web didn't help me at all, especially because half the links to the project are broken now.

If anyone knows what's gone wrong here (or needs more details) please let me know.

Details:

Python version: 2.7.7 32 bit

Pygame version: 1.9.3 32 bit

PyInstaller version: 1.5 32 bit

System: Windows 8.1 64 bit (the 32 bit programs have all worked fine so far though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find out what the problem was but I did manage to get it working. I started by installing the newer version of PyInstaller (2.1) with pip and completing the same steps again, but this time in the Scripts directory and running pyi-makespec and pyi-build instead of makespec.py and build.py because that's how the new version works, I guess. At first it would still complain about the resources being missing unless I ran it from cmd, but I think that was actually because I forgot step 5 (Tree in the makespec file). For some reason now the .exe can't permanently save the highscores, but apart from that it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

Try to open command prompt and drag exe into it and press enter, that way you will catch the error (if there is any) and then update your question, more info == more help.

I never used pyinstaller so I can't really help you on that.

Also I suggest you to try py2exe, it worked nicely with pygame (at least for me) and later you can make setup with NSIS or Inno.

### Edit:

If the .exe can't permanently save the highscores (as you said in comment below) try running exe as admin, it might be just matter of write privileges , or maybe it is your antivirus who doesn't allow it to write (sandbox at Avast, unknown/rare file at Norton).

Comment: Thanks! I did that and it according to the error it can't find my resources after all. I tried copying the directory into the same folder as the game but that didn't work either, so I guess something went wrong with the resources, but I'm not sure what - I'll edit my question soon.

As for py2exe, I actually tried that once too and it worked, but only for a while. I have no idea why but a few days later it stopped working and no matter what I tried it wouldn't work for anything but a simple Hello World program. I had a question about that on here too but it's still unanswered...

Comment: Sounds like you didn't tell PyInstaller where to look for resources or it is to dumb to find them. Again I don't know how it works so I might be wrong

Comment: @MMM I would suggest py2exe.

Comment: @pss Haha see I'd like to think that would work better but I already insisted on py2exe so much (6 months if you look at the timestamp of my last question) before moving on to PyInstaller that I've actually become physically ill with the amount of sleep and sanity I lost. And I still have no idea why it decided it doesn't want to convert my game anymore, won't convert a version of my game it worked with before anymore either but will still compile Hello World. Basically I'll only consider/be able to use py2exe again if someone tells me how to fix the "Segmentation Fault" I keep on getting.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to the same very question.
A nice way of solving it, **especially, if you are using Tkinter/CustomTkinter**, would be to follow these steps:

https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/Packaging#windows-pyinstaller-auto-py-to-exe

I was trying to use **pyinstaller** but without luck, some packages and json files where not included in the final build, therefore it did not work for me.
Using auto-py-to-exe solved the problem.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34747983)