# python .exe not working properly

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I downloaded pyinstaller in order to turn my python scripts into an executable program. I have a main script ((homepage.py) that, when ran, it would display a window with two buttons (button1 and button2). Each of the two buttons, if clicked, would run its corresponding python script (input1.py or input2.py) that displays a window where the user inputs data to be graphed in excel.

My scripts work correctly when I run them in Spyder through Anaconda. However, when I turn my main script (Homepage.py) into an executable program and run it, the main window with the two buttons appear, but when I click any of the two buttons, the corresponding window does not appear and the program closes. Does anyone know why that would happen? Do I need to turn my input1.py and input2.py into .exe programs as well like I did with homepage.py?

In my scripts, when I need click any of the buttons, I would hide the main window and show the new window. Would hiding and showing be what is causing my program to not function correctly even if it is working in Spyder?

main window (homapge.py) imports and class name,

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from input1 import Ui_input1
from input2 import Ui_input2

class Ui_homepage(object):
```

button1 (input1.py) imports and class name,

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import csv, os, subprocess, output1

class Ui_input1(object):
```

button2 (input2.py) imports and class name,

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import csv, os, subprocess, output2

class Ui_input2(object):
```

Also, inside both of input1.py and input2.py, I have a button function that returns to the main window (homepage.py) when clicked, and inside that function I import,

```
from homepage import Ui_homepage
```

At the end of homepage.py, input1.py, and input2.py I have this import,

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
```

Let me know if you need any more clarification or code.

**EDIT 1:**

The code that I use in the main window (homepage.py) that calls button1,

```
self.button1.clicked.connect(self.displayWindow1)

def displayWindow1(self):
    self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.uiInput1 = Ui_input1()
    self.uiInput1.setupUi(self.window)
    self.homepage.hide()
    self.window.showMaximized()
```

The code that I use in the main window (homepage.py) that calls button2,

```
self.button2.clicked.connect(self.displayWindow2)

def displayWindow1(self):
    self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.uiInput2 = Ui_input1()
    self.uiInput2.setupUi(self.window)
    self.homepage.hide()
    self.window.showMaximized()
```

**EDIT 2**:

I tried running the program after I changed,

```
from input1 import Ui_input1
from input2 import Ui_input2
```

to,

```
import input1 
import input2
```

I got this error in the command prompt window after typing **pyinstaller --onefile --windowed homepage.exe**,

```
25160 WARNING: lib not found: MSVCR90.dll dependency of c:\users\bj914e
\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\zlib.dll
```

and I got these errors in a warnhomepage.txt file,

```
missing module named resource - imported by posix, C:\Users\bj914e\Desktop
\DAMS\DAMS_Version_4\homepage.py
missing module named posix - imported by os, C:\Users\bj914e\Desktop
\DAMS\DAMS_Version_4\homepage.py
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess, C:\Users
\bj914e\Desktop\DAMS\DAMS_Version_4\homepage.py
missing module named org - imported by pickle, C:\Users\bj914e\Desktop
\DAMS\DAMS_Version_4\homepage.py
missing module named readline - imported by cmd, code, pdb, C:\Users
\bj914e\Desktop\DAMS\DAMS_Version_4\homepage.py
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib, 
importlib.abc, C:\Users\bj914e\Desktop\DAMS\DAMS_Version_4\homepage.py
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by 
importlib._bootstrap, importlib, importlib.abc, C:\Users\bj914e\Desktop
\DAMS\DAMS_Version_4\homepage.py
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform, C:\Users\bj914e
\Desktop\DAMS\DAMS_Version_4\homepage.py
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request
missing module named java - imported by platform, C:\Users\bj914e\Desktop
\DAMS\DAMS_Version_4\homepage.py
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform, C:\Users\bj914e
\Desktop\DAMS\DAMS_Version_4\homepage.py, xml.sax._exceptions
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform, C:\Users\bj914e
\Desktop\DAMS\DAMS_Version_4\homepage.py
missing module named termios - imported by tty, C:\Users\bj914e\Desktop
\DAMS\DAMS_Version_4\homepage.py, getpass
missing module named grp - imported by shutil, tarfile, C:\Users\bj914e
\Desktop\DAMS\DAMS_Version_4\homepage.py
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath, shutil, tarfile, 
http.server, webbrowser, C:\Users\bj914e\Desktop\DAMS\DAMS_Version_4
\homepage.py, netrc, getpass
missing module named _dummy_threading - imported by dummy_threading, 
C:\Users\bj914e\Desktop\DAMS\DAMS_Version_4\homepage.py
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy, C:\Users\bj914e
\Desktop\DAMS\DAMS_Version_4\homepage.py, xml.sax
missing module named cPickle - imported by xlsxwriter.compat_collections
missing module named cStringIO - imported by cPickle
missing module named copy_reg - imported by cPickle, cStringIO
missing module named StringIO - imported by xlsxwriter.compatibility
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code that you use in the main window that calls the button?

Comment: What do you mean by: when I turn my main script [...] into an executable program, run python script.py

Comment: @WoodyDev I added the codes for the buttons.

Comment: @jlandercy I fixed the wording. What I meant was when I turn homepage.py into homepage.exe and run homepage.exe, the homepage window appears, but when I click any of the buttons nothing happens and homepage.exe closes.

Comment: Have you tried putting input1.py and input2.py in the same directory as the .exe? Is there any error Message when starting the .exe in command line?

Comment: @MikeS I tried putting input1.py and input2.py in the same directory as the .exe, but it still does not work. I get no error messages when starting the .exe in the command line.

Comment: Update for anyone else needing help with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27486794/pyinstaller-exe-file-not-working
You can see

Comment: Answers do not belong in the text of the question itself; even as the OP, you should only add an answer using the "Add an Answer" / "Post Your Answer" button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a very similar problem, the issue was a missing module(s). Your exe may use other modules that pyinstaller did not detect. For me, as soon as I imported Decimal module my exe worked like a charm! When your homepage.exe closes/crashes, it tells you which module is missing. You will only have a millisecond to see it, I recorded my screen and slowed down the footage to see the error message. Unconventional, perhaps, but worked for me!

Comment: That was really helpful. I did not notice the command prompt that showed up and disappeared. I was able to see what my problem was and I fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've ran into this [issue here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1633) (basically the same as you but they're using TKinter).

The suggestion ([link again](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1633)) was to import the entire file like a module into your homepage.py program.

So change:

```
from input1 import Ui_input1
from input2 import Ui_input2
```

To:

```
import input1 
import input2
```

Let me know how it works out :-)

Comment: I tried your solution, but it still does not fix my problem.

Comment: @prexos Does this answer give you any different results, or does it fail in the same way?

Comment: @Sagasaki It fails in the same way. I even tried **import homepage** instead of **from homepage import Ui_homepage** in the return to homepage functions in input1.py and input2.py

Comment: If I change **from input1 import Ui_input1** to **import input1**. Do I also change **self.uiInput1 = Ui_input1()** to **self.uiInput1 = input1.Ui_input1()**? because I tried in another compiler and I got the error that input1 is imported but not used. @WoodyDev

Comment: Hi @prexos , yeah you should be using it like **self.uiInput1 = input1.UI_input1()** if you import the whole contents of the file (using the imports specified in my answer at least)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, the way I resolved this was by adding `--onefile` option  that pyinstaller provides. By executing `pyinstaller --onefile filename.py`, it created a one application file without any library dependency in the dist folder.